# Socket.io and React Native, cannot emit event from phone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, socket.io

Trying to get socket.io working with RN. I have verified the connection establishes successfully and the server will get an event trigger once the client connects, but that is all.

As you can see in my server, I have a couple custom events. I try to emit these events from the React Native code, but nothing triggers and I'm not sure why.

I've tried throwing the emit function in the RN code in different function, but I'm getting no logs on my server. What is the cause of this?

> I've simplified the RN code to elucidate the parts that matter most.

## Basic Server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const path = require('path');

const PORT_NUM = 3000;

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log('someone joined!', socket.id);
});

io.on('sendKeys', () => {
    console.log('keys callde!');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

server.listen(PORT_NUM, () => {
    console.log(`Web Socket Encryption Server Running on *:${PORT_NUM}...`);
});
```

---

## React Native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';

class ControlPanel extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

        };

        this.socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.32:3000', { 
            reconnectionDelay: 1000,
            reconnection: true,
            reconnectionAttempts: 10,
            transports: ['websocket'],
            agent: false,
            upgrade: false,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        });

        this.socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('Mobile Client Socket Connected.');
        });

        this.socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
          this.generateKeys();
    }

    async generateKeys() {
        this.socket.emit('sendKeys');
    }

    toggleLoader() { 
        this.setState({
            visible: !this.state.visible
        });
    }

    toggleKeysGenerated() {
        this.setState({
            keysGenerated: true
        });
    }

    render() {
     }
}



export default ControlPanel;
```

Comment: hey man i have the exact same problem did you solve this ?